# Format string was not in a correct format when trying to create new object

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a method where it is possible to create a product. But when i convert the different inputs to the correct format i get an error. 
The error is this

> [FormatException: string was not in a correct format.]
>      System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +12099621
>      System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +120
>      System.Convert.ToInt32(String value) +44
>      EPWebApp.NewProduct.btnSaveNewItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Europoultry\Program\EPWCF\EPSystem\EPWebApp\NewProduct.aspx.cs:450
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9671538
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +108
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1639

Here is where i call the method on the server side.

```
protected void btnSaveNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        svc.CreateNewProduct(
            txtNewGtin.Text,
            ddNewTargetMarket.DataValueField,
            Convert.ToString(datepicker1.Value),
            Convert.ToString(datepicker2.Value),
            Convert.ToString(txtNewLastChanged.Text),
            txtNewGLNNr.Text,
            txtNewGLNName.Text,
            hiddenRFIDValue.Value.ToString(),
            hiddenIsTradeItemACombinationItem.Value.ToString(),
            Convert.ToBoolean(hiddenHasBatchNumber.Value.ToLower()),
            ddNewTradeChannel.DataValueField,
            Convert.ToDecimal(txtNewNetContent.Text),
            ddnewNetContent.DataValueField,
            Convert.ToDecimal(txtNewGrossWeight.Text),
            ddNewGrossWeight.DataValueField,
            Convert.ToDecimal(txtNewNetWeight.Text),
            ddNewNetWeight.DataValueField,
            Convert.ToDecimal(txtNewHeight.Text),
            ddNewHeight.DataValueField,
            Convert.ToDecimal(txtNewWidth.Text),
            ddNewWidth.DataValueField,
            Convert.ToDecimal(txtNewDepth.Text),
            ddNewDepth.DataValueField,
            Convert.ToBoolean(hiddenIsBasePriceDeclarationRelevant.Value.ToLower()),
            Convert.ToBoolean(hiddenIsBarCodeOnPackageVariableMeasureBarCode.Value.ToLower()),
            Convert.ToBoolean(hiddenIsPackagingMarkedReturnable.Value.ToLower()),
            ddNewPackaginTypeCode.DataValueField,
            ddNewPACKMATERIALCODE.DataValueField,
            Convert.ToDecimal(txtNewPCKMATERIALCOMPOSITIONQTY.Text),
            ddPCKMATERIALCOMPOSITIONQTY.DataValueField,
            Convert.ToBoolean(hiddenIsTradeItemAConsumerUnit.Value.ToLower()),
            Convert.ToBoolean(hiddenIsTradeItemADespatchUnit.Value.ToLower()),
            Convert.ToBoolean(hiddenIsTradeItemAnOrdableUnit.Value.ToLower()),
            Convert.ToBoolean(hiddenIsTradeItemAnInvoiceUnit.Value.ToLower()),
            Convert.ToString(datepicker3.Value),
            txtNewCountryOfOrigin.Text,
            hiddenOrganicInformation.Value.ToString(),
            ddDescriptionOfSizeAndContent.DataValueField,
            txtNewDescriptionOfSizeAndContent.Text,
            hiddenRawMaterialIrradiatedCode.Value.ToString(),
            hiddenTradeIrradiatedCode.Value.ToString(),
            hiddenIngredientIrradiatedCode.Value.ToString(),
            ddNewPreservationTechniqueCodes.DataValueField,
            ddNewTradeItemUnitDesc.DataValueField,
            txtNewBrandName.Text,
            Convert.ToBoolean(hiddenIsTradeItemBaseUnit.Value.ToLower()),
            ddNewDescriptionLanguage.DataValueField,
            txtNewFunctionalName.Text,
            txtNewShortDescription.Text,
            Convert.ToInt32(txtNewMinimumStorageTemperature.Text),
            ddNewMinimumStorageTemperature.DataValueField,
            Convert.ToInt32(txtNewMaximumStorageTemperature.Text),
            ddNewMaximumStorageTemperature.DataValueField,
            txtNewGPCNr.Text,
            txtNewArticleNr.Text,
            ddImportClassificationType.DataValueField,
            Convert.ToInt32(txtNewImportClassificationType.Text),
            Convert.ToBoolean(hiddenIsPackMarkedWithIngredients.Value.ToLower()),
            Convert.ToBoolean(hiddenIsPriceOnPack.Value.ToLower()),
            DropDownList1.DataValueField,
            ddNewPackageMarksHigienic.DataValueField,
            ddNewExpirationDateTypeCode.DataValueField,
            ddPackageMarksDietOrAllergenCode.DataValueField,
            Convert.ToInt32(ddNewEUSubsidyCategoryAgencyName.DataValueField),
            ddNewTaxTypeCode.DataValueField,
            ddNewTaxAgencyCode.DataValueField,
            ddNewTaxApplicabilityCode.DataValueField,
            Convert.ToInt32(txtNewTaxRate.Text),
            ddNewMinimumTradeItemLifespanFromTimeOfProduction.DataValueField,
            Convert.ToInt32(txtNewMinimumTradeItemLifespanFromTimeOfProduction.Text),
            ddNewMinimumTradeItemLifespanFromTimeOfArrival.DataValueField,
            Convert.ToInt32(txtNewMinimumTradeItemLifespanFromTimeOfArrival.Text),
            hiddenIsDangerousSubstance.Value.ToString(),
            Convert.ToInt32(txtNewPreparedKCalQuantityContained.Text),
            Convert.ToInt32(txtNewPreparedKJoQuantityContained.Text),
            ddNewPreparedMeasurementPrecision.DataValueField,
            Convert.ToInt32(txtNewPreparedServingSize.Text),
            ddNewPreparedServingSize.DataValueField,
            Convert.ToInt32(txtNewUnPreparedKCalQuantityContained.Text),
            Convert.ToInt32(NewUnPreparedKJoQuantityContained.Text),
            ddNewUnPreparedMeasurementPrecision.DataValueField,
            Convert.ToInt32(txtNewUnPreparedServingSize.Text),
            ddNewUnPreparedServingSize.DataValueField);

        AddAllAllergenToItem();
        AddAllAdditiveAndEnumbers();
        AddAllNutrientValues();
        AddAllPreparationInformations();

    }
```

And here is the method that is called.

```
public void CreateNewProduct(string gtin, string targetMarket, string effectiveDate, string publicationDate, string lastChanged, string glnNr, string glnName, string rfid, string isTradeItemAnCombination, bool hasBatchNr, string tradeItemChannel, decimal netContentValue, string netContentMeasure, decimal grossWeightValue, string grossWeightMeasure, decimal netWeightValue, string netWeightMeasure, decimal heightValue, string heightMeasure, decimal widthValue, string widthMeasure, decimal depthValue, string depthMeasure, bool isBasePriceDeclarationRelevant, bool isTradeItemAVariableUnit, bool isPackagingMarkedReturnable, string packagingType, string packagingMaterial, decimal materialCompositionQtyValue, string materialCompositionMeasure, bool isTradeItemAConsumerUnit, bool isTradeItemADespatchUnit, bool isTradeItemAnOrderableUnit, bool isTradeItemAnInvoiceUnit, string startAvailabilityDateTime, string countryOfOrigin, string productOrigin, string descriptiveSizeLanguage, string descriptiveSizeLanguageValue, string rawMaterialIrradiateCode, string tradeItemIrradiatedCode, string ingredientIrradiatedCode, string preservationTechniqueCodes, string tradeItemUnitDescriptor, string brandName, bool isTradeItemAbaseUnit, string languageCode, string functionalName, string descriptionShort, int minStorageTemperatureValue, string minStorageTemperatureMeasure, int maxStorageTemperatureValue, string maxStorageTemperatureMeasure, string gPCBrickCode, string additionalTradeItemIdentificationValue, string classificationType, int classificationValue, bool isPackagingMarkedWithIngredients, bool isPriceOnPack, string barcodeType, string packageMarksHygienic, string expirationDateTypeCode, string packageMarksDietOrAllergenCode, int eUSubsidyAgencyCode, string applicabilityTaxTypeCode, string applicabilityTaxAgencyCode, string applicabilityCode, int taxRate, string minTradeItemLifeSpanFromTimeOfProduction, int minTradeItemLifeSpanFromTimeOfProductionvalue, string minTradeItemLifeSpanFromTimeOfArrival, int minTradeItemLifeSpanFromTimeOfArrivalvalue, string isDangerousSubstance, int preParedcalorificValueInKilocalories, int preParedcalorificValueInKilojoules, string preParedmeasurementPrecision, int preParednutritionalReferenceValue, string preParednutritionalReferenceMeasure, int unPreparedcalorificValueInKilocalories, int unPreparedcalorificValueInKilojoules, string unPreparedmeasurementPrecision, int unPreparednutritionalReferenceValue, string unPreparednutritionalReferenceMeasure)
    {
        CreateTradeItem(gtin, targetMarket, effectiveDate, publicationDate, lastChanged, glnNr, glnName, rfid, isTradeItemAnCombination, hasBatchNr, tradeItemChannel, 
            GetNewestDimensiomsId(), GetNewestPackageId(), GetNewestItemStatusId(), GetNewestOriginId(), GetNewestOrganicInformationId(), GetNewestSizeDescriptionId(), GetNewestItemProcessingTypeId(), GetNewestFoodDrinkAndTobacco(), GetNewestLifespanId(), GerNewestisDangerousSubstanceId(), GetNewestItemIdentitiesId(), GetNewestStorageAndHandelingId(), GetNewestProductClassificationId(), GetNewestMarkId(), GetNewestTaxAndSubsidiesId(), GetNewestPreparedNutrientInformationId(), GetNewestUnPreparedNutrientInformationId());

        CreateDimensions(netContentValue, netContentMeasure, grossWeightValue, grossWeightMeasure, netWeightValue, netWeightMeasure, heightValue, heightMeasure, widthValue, widthMeasure, depthValue, depthMeasure, isBasePriceDeclarationRelevant, isTradeItemAVariableUnit);

        CreatePackage(isPackagingMarkedReturnable, packagingType, packagingMaterial, materialCompositionQtyValue, materialCompositionMeasure);

        CreateTradeItemStatus(isTradeItemAConsumerUnit, isTradeItemADespatchUnit, isTradeItemAnOrderableUnit, isTradeItemAnInvoiceUnit, startAvailabilityDateTime);

        CreateOrigin(countryOfOrigin);

        CreateOrganicInformation(productOrigin);

        CreateSizeDescription(descriptiveSizeLanguage, descriptiveSizeLanguageValue);

        CreateItemProcessingType(rawMaterialIrradiateCode, tradeItemIrradiatedCode, ingredientIrradiatedCode);

        CreateFoodDrinkAndTobacco(preservationTechniqueCodes);

        CreateItemIdentities(tradeItemUnitDescriptor, brandName, isTradeItemAbaseUnit, languageCode, functionalName, descriptionShort);

        CreateStorageAndHandeling(minStorageTemperatureValue, minStorageTemperatureMeasure, maxStorageTemperatureValue, maxStorageTemperatureMeasure);

        CreateProductClassification(gPCBrickCode, additionalTradeItemIdentificationValue, classificationType, classificationValue);

        CreateMarks(isPackagingMarkedWithIngredients, isPriceOnPack, barcodeType, packageMarksHygienic, expirationDateTypeCode, packageMarksDietOrAllergenCode);

        CreateTaxAndSubsidies(eUSubsidyAgencyCode, applicabilityTaxTypeCode, applicabilityTaxAgencyCode, applicabilityCode, taxRate);

        CreateLifespan(minTradeItemLifeSpanFromTimeOfProduction, minTradeItemLifeSpanFromTimeOfProductionvalue, minTradeItemLifeSpanFromTimeOfArrival, minTradeItemLifeSpanFromTimeOfArrivalvalue);

        CreateDangerousSubstance(isDangerousSubstance);

        CreatePreparedNutrientInformation(preParedcalorificValueInKilocalories, preParedcalorificValueInKilojoules, preParedmeasurementPrecision, preParednutritionalReferenceValue, preParednutritionalReferenceMeasure);

        CreateUnPreparedNutrientInformation(unPreparedcalorificValueInKilocalories, unPreparedcalorificValueInKilojoules, unPreparedmeasurementPrecision, unPreparednutritionalReferenceValue, unPreparednutritionalReferenceMeasure);

        CreateItemsOverview(gtin, brandName, tradeItemChannel, functionalName, tradeItemUnitDescriptor, lastChanged, GetNewestTradeItemsId());
    }
```

I have check all of the parameters that the method gets, and all of them should be in the right format.

Comment: You should show _only_ the **relevant** line that throws this exception. Show the string value that you try to parse and tell what culture you use.

Comment: The problem is that it dosent give an relevant line where the problem is.. I just gives the line where the method is called.

Comment: Then you should set a break point and debug your method. Check your values and `Text` properties of your controls. http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: That code looks horrific!

Comment: Probably you are passing to one of the Convert.ToInt32 and empty string or a null value.... debug it...

Comment: As the exception says there is problem while converting a value to Int32 using `Convert.ToInt32()`. Check all the controls which are being converted to Int32. Error producing value may be Non-Numeric, space or even blank.

Comment: @KevinJensen on the contrary, the error message says that a `Convert.ToInt32` inside `btnSaveNewItem_Click` failed. This is used in only *one* line, at the point where `svc.CreateNewProduct`. Parsing in the same line where you call another method though is a very, very bad idea as you found out - there's no way to know which value is bad, even if you debug. Extract the parsing calls to separate lines.

Comment: When i debug i get this error. **An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code** and it gives some troubleshooting tips about how to convert a datetime. But there should not be any problems with datetime since i am getting the datetime input from a textbox and that i already a string

Comment: @KevinJensen read the error message. It isn't about dates, it's about **ints**. Debuging won't help because the code makes all parsing calls in a single line. Fix your code first by parsing each property separately and storing it in a variable. Otherwise the only way to find the problem is to check the 14 text values one by one

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so you suggest making varaiables of all of the value and convert them there, insteadt of where i am doing it now?

Comment: 1, Breakpoint 2, Debug

Comment: Yes. What you are doing now *does* create temporary objects, you just don't see them nor can you debug the calls, or even put a breakpoint

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos okay i see. I makes good sense to create some variables. I will try this hopfully it works

Comment: I hope you find the answer but in terms of the code I would consider the "FacadePattern" Button click instantiates a "CreateProductFacade" then in that facade create private sub-actions that relate to Creating a product.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It worked! now i can se what parameter that is the wrong format.

Answer (score 0):

The answer stays in the exception.

You call a Method of the Converter class, in which you try to parse a string which is not valid, because there are some non-numerical (special characters, alphabetical letters) characters in it.

You can try to convert the values in an try-catch block.

```
    try
    {
        //your method call
    }
    catch(FormatException ex)
    {
        //some handling
    }
```